# discreetness, secrecy

Tags: word-choice, nouns, formality

Is paraphrasing:

> I expect you to keep this subject secret from people it does not concern.

as

> I'm expecting discreetness concerning this subject.

a correct use of that word? How else would you formally, elegantly, subtly describe the requirement of restricting the reach of certain information (especially in noun form)?

I'd prefer to avoid strict, technical language related to "classified", or "closed circulation" etc. Keep it on subtle, polite side please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine, but I'd use *discretion* rather than *discreetness*.

> I'm expecting discretion concerning this subject.

FreeDictionary definitions:

> [dis·creet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discreetness)  (d-skrt) adj.
>   1.: Marked by, exercising, or showing prudence and wise self-restraint in speech and behavior; circumspect.
>
> dis·creetness n.

And:

> [dis·cre·tion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discretion)  (d-skrshn) n.
>   1. The quality of being discreet; circumspection.

Comment: Thanks. Google Docs insists I should correct this to discreteness, but that would totally change the meaning, wouldn't it?

Comment: *Discreet* and *discrete* are different words with different meanings. *Discreet* is being secretive, [*discrete*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discrete) is like distinct.